# /bin/sh: 1: open: not found. make: *** [Makefile: cloud-metabase] Error 127

Tags: bash, makefile

When I run `make cloud-metabase` command, I get the following error:

`/bin/sh: 1: open: not found make: *** [Makefile:66: cloud-metabase] Error 127`

The line in the Makefile that the error points to:

```
terraform -chdir=./terraform output -raw private_key > private_key.pem && chmod 600 private_key.pem && ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly 
yes" -i private_key.pem ubuntu@$$(terraform -chdir=./terraform output -raw ec2_public_dns) -N -f -L 3001:$$(terraform - 
chdir=./terraform output -raw ec2_public_dns):3000 && open http://localhost:3001 && rm private_key.pem
```

I tried to break down the Makefile line and see where's the problem. The following part works fine

```
terraform -chdir=./terraform output -raw private_key > private_key.pem && chmod 600 private_key.pem
```

When I call the following part, I get the following error:

```
ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly yes" -i private_key.pem ubuntu@$$(terraform -chdir=./terraform output -raw ec2_public_dns) -N -f -L 3001:$$(terraform -chdir=./terraform output -raw ec2_public_dns):3000 && open http://localhost:3001 && rm private_key.pem
```

Error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double dollar signs (`$`), and only insert one.

```bash
ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly yes" -i private_key.pem ubuntu@$(terraform -chdir=./terraform output -raw ec2_public_dns) -N -f -L 3001:$(terraform -chdir=./terraform output -raw ec2_public_dns):3000 && open http://localhost:3001 && rm private_key.pem
```

Comment: The reason the dollar sign is doubled in the Makefile is that it has special meaning to `make`. When you use the same code on the command line, you need to unescape any `make` escapes.